# Como atualizar cache de imagem via PHP

Tags: php, cache

Possuo uma imagem em miniatura no `header.php`, porém ao enviar um requisição de atualização dessa imagem para outra página em PHP (que atualiza a mesma no banco de dados), a mesma não é atualizada automaticamente na página.

**Obs.**: já inseri os seguintes cabeçalhos no header.php, sem sucesso:

```
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, cachehack=".time());
header("Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=-1, pre-check=-1", false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jeito mais garantido é adicionar um parâmetro novo no link da imagem. Exemplo: `imagem.jpg?20170724`. Se modificar amanhã ficaria algo como `imagem.jpg?20170725`.

Pode tentar todos esses truques com o `header()` mas nem sempre funcionará em todos os browsers como pode perceber. Em 18 anos lidando com isso, tentei todos esses `header pragma`, h`eader expires` e `header macumba vela preta` e quando pensava ter encontrado a combinação certa, uma atualização de browsers desandava tudo. Simplesmente desisti e optei pelo mais simples e óbvio que é adicionar a versão do arquivo como parâmetro ou a data e hora da última modificação.

No banco de dados, crie um campo "date_modified" e sempre que buscar a imagem, leia também esse campo para concatená-lo na URL.

Outra técnica usada é gerar um arquivo com novo nome único. Assim não precisaria se preocupar em colocar a data ou versão como parâmetro da URL. A desvantagem disso é se a imagem é usada para SEO pois a anterior é dada como *Not found* pelos mecanismos de busca e o site perde rankeamento na busca por images (google images, por exemplo).

Vale salientar que a técnica com parâmetro não atualiza o cache existente. O que acontece é que o cache permanece e é feito download do novo arquivo pois para o navegador, 1 parâmetro diferente é dado como novo arquivo.

Comment: Olá @DanielOmine, estou conseguindo alterar temporariamente pelo retorno Ajax, da seguinte forma: `$('#foto-perfil img').attr('src', 'imagens/perfil/'+data);`, sendo que data é um nome exclusivo, que é dado a nova imagem quando esta é alterada. Contudo, ao atualizar a página novamente a URL carregada é a antiga, mesmo estando com o novo nome no banco de dados. O que poderia estar acontecendo?

Comment: Aí nesse caso é o cache da página em si e não da imagem.